# Adding SimpleXML to array causes strange behavior

Tags: php, simplexml

When i want to add a SimpleXML Object to an array or do `array_map` or even simple things like this:

```php
$menu[] = $data;
// $data is SimpleXML Object.
```

causes `It is not yet possible to assign complex types to properties` error. This is some code that i've tried:

```php
//$data is SimpleXML object from $datas.
//$datas is SimpleXML object contains "Module" elements:

$menu[] = $data;
```

No luck: Still causes error. I use foreach to get the $data. so that's why. i've tried `foreach((array) $datas->Module as $data)`, no luck too.

---

```php
$menu = array_map(function($data) {
  return data;
}, $datas->Module);
```

this maybe a dumbest solution, but i added `(array)` too, and no luck.

---

```php
$i=0; $menu = [];
foreach($datas as $data){
  $menu[$i] = $data;
  $i++;
}
```

---

```php
array_push($menu, $data);
```

---

Everything is useless T^T. How to do it correctly, Adding SimpleXML object to an array (Pushing it)?

**EDIT**

XML String:

```xml
<Module name="Administrative Task" url="Admin" icon="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" rule_name="url_administrative" rule_min="R">
  <Submodule name="User Management" url="User">
    <Proccess name="Add New" url="New"/>
  </Submodule>
</Module>

<Module name="Lisencing Systems" url="Lisensi" icon="glyphicon glyphicon-book" rule_name="url_licensing" rule_min="RWUD">
  <Submodule name="User Management" url="User">
    <Proccess name="Add New" url="New"/>
  </Submodule>
</Module>
```

Comment: In your `array_map` line, you are passing `$datas->Module`, which is not an array, it's a SimpleXMLElement object. The `$menu[] = $data` line should work fine, as should the `foreach`: https://3v4l.org/0HIKE

Comment: I can't actually reproduce the error you've given. Please can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] so we can help understand where the error is coming from.

Comment: i've updated the question, i use php 5.6.1, is this related with my php engine?

Comment: You can use an online tool like http://3v4l.org to test how code works in different versions of PHP. What you need to come up with is *an actual piece of PHP code which gives the error*. Have a look at the help article linked in my last comment for tips.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you change your XML string like below.

```
<?php  error_reporting(E_ALL);
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<row>
   <Module> 
    <name>Administrative Task</name>
    <url>Admin</url> 
    <icon>glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt</icon> 
    <rule_name>url_administrative</rule_name> 
    <rule_min>R</rule_min>
        <Submodule>
            <name>User Management</name> 
            <url>User</url>
            <Proccessname>Add New</Proccessname> 
            <url>New</url>
        </Submodule>
</Module>
 <Module>
    <name>Lisencing Systems</name> 
    <url>Lisensi</url> 
    <icon>glyphicon glyphicon-book</icon> 
    <rule_name>url_licensing</rule_name> 
    <rule_min>RWUD</rule_min>
        <Submodule> 
            <name>User Management</name> 
            <url>User</url>
            <Proccessname>Add New</Proccessname> 
            <url>New</url>
     </Submodule>
   </Module>
 </row>';

$simple = simplexml_load_string($xml);
// var_dump($simple);

$arr = json_decode( json_encode($simple) , 1);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Changing the structure of the input is very rarely an option, and I'm not sure why it would be necessary in this case. Plus I strongly believe that the `json_decode(json_encode())` trick creates far more problems than it solves.

Comment: I tried to use the XML string what **Kekesed** provided in his question. But the `simplexml_load_string()` not give any result when i use the same XML string. That's why i changed the structure. But i have no idea how the `json_decode(json_encode())` will working in that case.

Comment: Sure, but that's like saying "I tried to get into your house, but I couldn't find the front door, so I went to my own house instead". Most of the time, people are trying to parse somebody else's data, so saying "use a different input" doesn't help.